# C# и запись в .rtf-шаблон

Tags: c#, mysql, кодировка, rtf

коллеги.

Есть БД MySQL с русским текстом.
Есть приложение C# WinForms x86 .net 3.5.
Есть файл `.rtf` с вставками вида #template# и русским текстом.

Задача: записать текст из БД в нужные места в файле.
Читаю через `File.ReadAllText`, затем склеиваю строки и пишу обратно через `File.WriteAllText` в новый файл.

И получаю кракозябры вместо вставленного текста. При этом тот текст, что был, остаётся в порядке.

Пробовал читать в одной кодировке, писать в другой... Один пёс.

Может, кто-то сталкивался с этим `.rtf` - какую комбинацию кодировок посоветуете для базы данных, самого файла, `File.ReadAllText` и `File.WriteAllText`? Или может юзать `File.Write/ReadAllBytes`. Или перекодировать на лету вставляемые куски текста?

Заранее спасибо.

Я до сих пор не въехал, какая родная кодировка у `.rtf` - 1251 или 1252.

UPD:
Код:

```
string agreementTemplate = File.ReadAllText("PaymentTemplate.rtf", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
agreementTemplate = agreementTemplate.Replace("#klientName#", CurrentCredit.Client);
agreementTemplate = agreementTemplate.Replace("#klientAdr#", CurrentCredit.ClientAdr);
File.WriteAllText("Сведения о платежах для договора №" + CurrentCredit.Number + ".doc", agreementTemplate, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

Результат:
Андрей Семёнов
óë. Ëåíèíà, 24

Добавил новый файл для примера.
При загрузке:
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset204 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}\r\n\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang1049\f0\fs22\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\b\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\ul\b0\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\b\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\ulnone\b0\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2: \lang1033\f1 #replace#\par\r\n\lang1049\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\par\r\n\par\r\n}\r\n"

После замены replace на русский текст

"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset204 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}\r\n\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang1049\f0\fs22\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\b\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\ul\b0\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\b\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\ulnone\b0\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2: \lang1033\f1\'c0\'ed\'e4\'f0\'e5\'e9 \'d1\'e5\'ec\'b8\'ed\'ee\'e2\par\r\n\lang1049\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\lang1049\f0\'d0\'f3\'f1\'f1\'ea\'e8\'e9 \'f2\'e5\'ea\'f1\'f2\lang1033\f1\par\r\n\par\r\n\par\r\n}\r\n"

Содержимое файла

Русский текст
Русский текст (жирным)
Русский текст (подчёркнутым)
Русский текст (жирным подч)
Русский текст
Русский текст: #replace#
Русский текст
Русский текст

Обновление: решение проблемы, как обычно, с помощью костылей. Вместо шаблона вида "#replace#" делаем шаблон КИРИЛЛИЦЕЙ вида "ИмяКлиента".

То есть текст в шаблоне: "клиент, в лице ИмяКлиента, обязывается..."

Затем, с помощью функции, предложенной nick_n_a, делаем такую кракозябру:

```
templateStr = loadfile...
templateStr = templateStr.Replace(ToRtf("ИмяКлиента"), ToRtf(CurrentCredit.Name));
```

где CurrentCredit.Name - русский текст из БД
На кодировку ложим болт ибо теперь неважно.

В общем, оно работает. Но... сами понимаете. Кто придумает что-то лучше - милости просим)

ЗЫ: правда, на основных файлах ещё не проверял, если что - вернусь)

Comment: Richtextbox. LoadFile/SaveFile

Comment: А форматирование и таблицы это не испортит? Я щас просто не у компьютера.

Comment: "Я до сих пор не въехал, какая родная кодировка у .rtf - 1251 или 1252." - Никакая. Все не-ASCII символы указываются в виде escape-последовательностей, либо с номером символа из указанной явно кодовой страницы ANSI, либо юникодовским кодом символа.

Comment: @Александр как я и думал - форматирование и таблицы в тартарары

Comment: Я предложил вариант без "сторонних" библиотек. Существует ли хорошая библиотека для работы с rtf  для с# - возможно да. Будет ли она работать быстрее - я сомневаюсь:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всё заработало в итоге.

```
//виртуальный буфер (глобальная переменная)
private RichTextBox _richTextBox = new RichTextBox();

//название файла для сохранения
string target = "Договор №" + CurrentCredit.Number + ".doc";
//грузим шаблон в RichTextBox - контрол сам порешает за все кодировки
_richTextBox.LoadFile(Storage.AgreementTemplateFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
//магия
Replace("#nomer#", CurrentCredit.Number.ToString());
//при сохранении о кодировке опять-таки позаботится RichTextBox
_richTextBox.SaveFile(target);

//главное - функция Replace:

private void Replace(string from, string to)
{
    int start = _richTextBox.Find(from, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    _richTextBox.Select(start, from.Length);
    _richTextBox.SelectedText = to;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для вставки текста RTF в шаблон я использовал такое приведение

```
  public static string toRTF(string value)
        {  /*Конвертирует текст, в текст пригодный для RTF документа */
            //                                                                                                             FF
            string syms = @"ЎўЈЈ¤Ґ¦§Ё©Є«¬­®Ї°±Ііґµ¶•ё№є»јЅѕїАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";                      
            string rep_1 = @"0123456789abcdef";
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            while (j < value.Length)
            {
                if (syms.IndexOf(value[j]) >= 0)
                {
                    k = syms.IndexOf(value[j]);
                    value = value.Replace(value[j].ToString(), "\\'" + rep_1[(k / 16) + 10].ToString() + rep_1[k & 15].ToString());
                };
                j++;
            };
            value = value.Replace("\\n", "\\par;");
            return value;
        }
```

Да.. пожалуй хранить и копировать таблицу сложно... вариант 2 - без таблицы

```
  public static string toRTF(string value)
        {  /*Конвертирует текст, в текст пригодный для RTF документа */
            byte[] t = new byte[1];
            int j = 0;                
            while (j < value.Length)
            {
                if (value[j] >= '\x7F')
                {
                    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(value,j,1,t,0);                      
                    value = value.Replace(value[j].ToString(), "\\'" + t[0].ToString('x'));
                };
                j++;
            };
            value = value.Replace("\\n", "\\par;");
            return value;
        }
```

Т.е. буква я маленькая имеет код  `\'FF`. Плюс... шаблон должен содержать метку 1251, т.е. в файле с поддержкой 1251 заголовок должен быть такой

```
 {\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1251\
```

Еще я заменяю возврат каретки на `\par;` потому что текст так переносится в rtf.

Текст можно вообще не преобразовывать, оставить как есть и лишь перенести в кодировку 1251, если есть уверенность, что ваш файл будут открывать исключительно в среде windows. Некоторые "неродные" редакторы не понимают файлы без указанного перевода.

P.S. RTF не самый простой формат, не могу рассказать подробно о его деталях. Приведенный код использую в одном из проэктов. Преобразование в heх можно реализовать лучше.. но так уже получилось - не само оптимально. В вики внизу есть ссылка на спецификацию http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format, если есть сложности - думаю спецификацикация даст ответ на ваши вопросы.

Comment: А в какой кодировке читаешь файл? И в какой пишешь? Самое забавное, что часть текста (из одной таблицы, КАРЛ), сохраняет правильно, а часть - кракозябрами.

Comment: Изменил `k = syms.IndexOf(value[j]);` на `k = syms.IndexOf(value[j]) + 1;` - всё заработало. ???

Comment: Но опять не везде (см 1 коммент)

Comment: Всё равно это ничего особо не решает. Больше всего убивает, что некоторые записи сохраняются норм, а некоторые нет. И закономерности не вижу - спецсимволов там нет, обычные слова

Comment: Странно... Проблема может быть, разве что с неправильной таблицей символов которая может быть искажена копированием. Я для вас сделал вариант без неё. Симолы которые не входят в 1251 - не будут верно отражены. Если у вас есть обратные слеши - их нужно тоже экранировать. Попробуйте вариант 2 (я тогда писал в1 - не знал ещё как таблицу получить), если нет - приведите конкретное слово - посмотрим.

Comment: Обновил вопрос - посмотрите

Comment: Нет, так не подходит. Какая строка на входе - и какая конкретно на выходе. Возможно у вас на "улице" выбран не кирилический шрифт. ул. какая?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить одинаковый шрифт и слева и справа от "Семёнов"

Comment: ул. Ленина - стандарт

Comment: ул. Ленина = `\'f3\'eb. \'cb\'e5\'ed\'e8\'ed\'e0` Я уверен что ф-ция вам дала такое же самое значение. Если нет - трассировка. Если да - то у вас проблема или с шрифтом (вероятнее всего поставлен не кирилический шрифт), или какая-то уж очень нестандартная, которую "на бум" решить не получится. Посмотрел дополнение... всётаки нету текста на входе, и текста на выходе. У меня не получается повторить вашу проблему, потому что не все параметры опубликованы.

Comment: Похоже, я не понял, что скинуть. См. обновление - "решение"

Comment: Я думаю... тут вкралась невнимательность. Вы публикуете следствие - а причину не видно. Как вы получили `\'c0\'ed\'e4\'f0\'e5\'e9 \'d1\'e5\'ec\'b8\'ed\'ee\'e2` ? "Русский текст" так конвертироваться не могло. И ул. Ленина тоже. Ваш пример нельзя проверить.

Comment: Как вариант - можете на время оставить текст без перекодирования в чистой 1251 кодировке. Офис это понимает. Неродные, линуксы и мобилки - могут каракули писать. Ситуация при этом вероятнее всего не изменется - но будет проще словить баг дебаггером. Ну 1 из 9 раз не верно - мне кажется тут у вас ошибка где-то вкралась.

Answer (score 0):

Если вас не интересует поддержка старого ПО, можно закодировать в Unicode, тогда проблемы кодировки не будет. Для этого пропустите строку через такой метод:

```
static string RtfEncode(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length * 4);

    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (c > 127) //заменяем не-ASCII символы на их Unicode представление
        {
            string escape = "\\u" + ((Int16)c).ToString() + "?";
            sb.Append(escape);
        }
        else //ASCII добавляем без изменений
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Тогда замену можно произвести как-то так:

```
string template = "#template#";
string word = "Иванов И.А.";
string contents = File.ReadAllText(input_file);

word = RtfEncode(word);
contents = contents.Replace(template, word);
File.WriteAllText(output_file, contents);
```

О кодировке не нужно заботиться, так как после RtfEncode задействованы только ASCII символы. При таком способе ничего не должно нарушиться, при условии что маркер замены в шаблоне никак не пересекает границы управляющих конструкций RTF. (Отредактируйте шаблон в блокноте, и убедитесь, что строка замены представлена именно так, как вы ожидаете.)